# Msql Join row results of a query

Tags: mysql, select, join

Please help with the following problem

I have a table: people

```
Id   Leader Name1   Name2   StartDate  EndDate
123  1      Person1         2013-02-11 2013-02-17
123  0              Person2 2013-02-13 2013-02-13
123  0              Person3 2013-02-13 2013-02-13
```

I have a query1

```
(SELECT t1.Id, t1.Name1, t1.Name2
FROM `dbo`.`people` t1
WHERE t1.StartDate >= '2013-02-11'
AND t1.Leader = 1)

UNION 

(SELECT t2.Id, t2.Name1, t1.Name2
FROM `dbo`.`people` t2
WHERE t2.StartDate >= '2013-02-11'
AND t2.Leader = 0)
```

This returns

```
Id   Name1   Name2
123, Person1
```

I have a query2

```
(SELECT t1.Id, t1.Name1, t1.Name2
FROM `dbo`.`people` t1
WHERE t1.StartDate >= '2013-02-13'
AND t1.Leader = 1)

UNION 

(SELECT t2.Id, t2.Name1, t1.Name2
FROM `dbo`.`people` t2
WHERE t2.StartDate >= '2013-02-13'
AND t2.Leader = 0)
```

This returns

```
Id   Name1   Name2
123, Person1 
123,         Person2
123,         Person3
```

I need the result for 2012-02-11 to show

```
Id   Name1   Name2
123, Person1 null
```

and for the 2012-02-13 to show

```
Id   Name1   Name2
123, Person1 Person2
123, Person1 Person3
```

Comment: Have you tried 'CROSS JOIN' instead of 'UNION'?

Comment: waht about start and end date in your desired result?

Comment: Hi Raheen, Nearly there but Id and Leader are not related, therefore cannot use ON pl.leader = p.id. Id is a counter and could be any value, Leader is an indicator and can only be 0 or 1. Can you suggest alternative. Thanks

Comment: The results of the queries do not match with the data you show. Are you sure you are using `>=` and not `<=` in the date comparisons?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query which fulfils your desired result

```
(SELECT 
  id,
  name1,
  IFNULL(name2, 'No one available') AS name2,
  startdate AS `date` 
FROM
  person 
WHERE startdate = '2013-02-11') 
UNION
ALL 
(SELECT 
  p.id,
  IFNULL(p.name1, pl.name1) AS name1,
  IFNULL(p.name2, 'Noone available') AS name2,
  p.startdate AS `DATE` 
FROM
  person AS p 
  LEFT JOIN person AS pl 
    ON pl.leader = p.id 
WHERE p.startdate = '2013-02-13')
```

Output

```
id  name1       name2               date
---------------------------------------------------
1   Person1     No one available    2013-02-11
1   Person1     Person2             2013-02-13
1   Person1     Person3             2013-02-13
```

Click [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32f868/1) for Demo

And Here is your query with a little modification

```
(SELECT 
  t1.Id,
  t1.Name1,
  IFNULL(t1.Name2, 'Null') AS Name2 
FROM
  `dbo`.`people` t1 
WHERE t1.StartDate >= '2013-02-13' 
  AND t1.Leader = 1) 
UNION
(SELECT 
  t2.Id,
  IFNULL(t2.Name1, p.leader) AS Name1,
  t1.Name2 
FROM
  `dbo`.`people` t2 
  LEFT JOIN people AS p 
    ON p.leader = t2.id 
WHERE t2.StartDate >= '2013-02-13' 
  AND t2.Leader = 0)
```

EDITS

The other alternative is to use a subquery

```
(SELECT 
  t1.Id,
  t1.Name1,
  IFNULL(t1.Name2, 'Null') AS Name2 
FROM
  `dbo`.`people` t1 
WHERE t1.StartDate >= '2013-02-13' 
  AND t1.Leader = 1) 
UNION
(SELECT 
  t2.Id,
  IFNULL(t2.Name1, (SELECT name1 FROM people WHERE t2.StartDate = '2013-02-13')) AS Name1,
  t2.Name2 
FROM
  `dbo`.`people` t2 
WHERE t2.StartDate >= '2013-02-13' 
  AND t2.Leader = 0)
```

Remove join and use a subquery while selection ifnull comes in name1 in the second part of union.
This query fetches results from table IFNULL checks if the Name1 field is empty or not . If this is empty execute second argument of IFNULL which is a subquery and will fetch a name. Please do some research on google if you need more help.

Comment: Hi Raheen, Nearly there but Id and Leader are not related, therefore cannot use ON pl.leader = p.id. Id is a counter and could be any value, Leader is an indicator and can only be 0 or 1. Can you suggest alternative. Thanks

Comment: Hi Raheen, I am newbie sorry, can you provide example to help me.

Comment: @user1254513 please see updates and also try doing some research on google or Stackoverflow. Sorry i am busy.